# How to check the token in localStorage is valid or not?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, react-redux, frontend

I am connecting ReactJS frontend with PHP backend. On login I'm saving the JWT Token in localStorage, I have some static react pages, which i want to show only when user is logged in I have wrapped them in a protected Route. I know when we are extracting data from backend api we can authorize user but in this case how can i authorize the user, the static pages are still accessible if user add the wrong token.
below is the code of my protected route

```
 <Route
      {...rest}
      component={(props) => {
        const token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
        if (token) {
          return <Component {...props} />;
        } else {
          return <Redirect to={"/"} />;
        }
      }}
    />
```

Comment: You can't secure anything in the front-end only. A user could just check the token value in the storage themselves, and modify as necessary.

Comment: You need to make a call to backend API with the token retrieved from `localStorage` and see if it's valid (backend will do the job of validation)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do following code for securing pages

- Add token in redux or localstorage
- On refresh, call api and send token to server that will validate your token
- If validated then you can show protected page otherwise redirect to login
- On server side make middleware that will check if request has token and its valid
- If not valid, send unauthorized response that you can intercept with axios if you are using axios. Or create middleware for response in reactjs

I think this can solve your problem of authenticating user